# Ansible create Users and Group

Tags: ansible

I am trying to create new users and groups using Ansible playbook. Below is my folder structure.

```
tree
.
├── create-users.yaml
└── ubuntu
```

`create-users.yaml` playbook contains create user and group tasks. Note, I am not having any group (admin_group) and users (Rajini, Kamal) in my target machine, instead they will be created when running the playbook.

```
---
- name:  Create Users & Groups
  hosts: target1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Create Users Task
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
        password: "{{ 'default_user_password' | password_hash('sha512','A512') }}"
        shell: /bin/bash
        groups: "{{ admin_group }}"
      loop:
        - Rajini
        - Kamal
```

I have another file called `ubuntu` to pick group name and password. When running the playbook I am getting below error.

```
ansible-playbook --vault-id @prompt create-users.yaml -K
BECOME password:
Vault password (default):

PLAY [Create Users & Groups] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Create Users Task] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [target1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'admin_group' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/osboxes/Ansible_Project/web_deployment/Ansible/groups_vars/create-users.yaml': line 6, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Create Users Task\n      ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
target1                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
admin_group: admin
default_user_password: Password1
```

Can somebody please help me on this?

Updating Output after getting help from user Moon.

```
ansible-playbook --vault-id @prompt create-users.yaml -K
BECOME password:
Vault password (default):

PLAY [Create Users & Groups] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Create Users Task] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [target1] => (item=Rajini)
changed: [target1] => (item=Kamal)

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
target1                    : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
ssh Kamal@192.168.0.1
Kamal@192.168.0.1's password:
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.0.0-23-generic x86_64)
Kamal@Ansible_Target1:~$ id
uid=1005(Kamal) gid=1001(admin) groups=1001(admin)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of things:

- To use variables from `ubuntu` file you need specify the vars file in playbook.
- To use `default_user_password` as a variable, remove the quotes `'`
- If you want `admin` as the users primary group then use `group` attribute instead. `groups` on the other hand takes a list and add the users to the listed groups.

And, if the group isn't created yet on the target machine then first create the group using [group module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/group_module.html).

Playbook after the above changes.

```yaml
---
- name: Create Users & Groups
  hosts: target1
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files: ubuntu
  tasks:
    - name: Create group
      group:
        name: "{{ admin_group }}"
        state: present

    - name: Create Users Task
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
        password: "{{ default_user_password | password_hash('sha512','A512') }}"
        shell: /bin/bash
        group: "{{ admin_group }}"
      loop:
        - Rajini
        - Kamal
```

Comment: thanks lot Moon, I changed my playbook as per your instruction, its working fine as we expected, please find the updated output for your references

Comment: In case if the group already exists, for example, group name is devops_admin then we can use append model to insert my newly joined user into the existing group?

Comment: Yes, use `groups` attribute to specify additional groups with `append`.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you make your playbook more dynamic:

- create a secret.yml file for storing user password using below command:

  ```
  ansible-vault create secret.yml
  #sample:
  user_password: mypass@155
  ```
- create userlist.yml to specify the list of user and their department:

vim userlist.yml

```
#sample:
##user matching job role mentioned in create-user.yml playbook will be created


    - users:
            - name: "user1"
              job: "developer"
    
            - name: "user2"
              job: "devops"
    
            - name: "user3"
              job: "developer"
```

- Now create your playbook as follows:

vim user-create.yml

```
   - hosts: appserver1
      vars_files: 
        - secret.yml
        - userlist.yml
    
      tasks:
        - name: "create group" 
          group:
            name: "{{ item  }}"  
          loop: 
              - "dev"
              - "devops"
          
        - name: "create user when Job=developer from userlist.yml file with password from secret.yml file and add to secondary group 'dev' "
          user: 
            name: "{{ item['name'] }}"
            password: "{{ user_password | password_hash('sha512')  }}"   
            update_password: on_create 
            groups: "dev"
            append: yes
          loop: "{{ users }}"
          when: "item['job'] == 'developer'"
    
    
        - name: "create user when Job=devops from userlist.yml file with password from secret.yml file and add to secondary group 'devops' "
          user:
            name: "{{ item['name']  }}"
            password: "{{ user_password | password_hash('sha512')  }}"
            update_password: on_create
            groups: "devops"
            append: yes
          loop: "{{ users }}"
          when: "item['job'] == 'devops'"
```

*Run the playbook*

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory  user-create.yml  --ask-vault-pass
```

*Things to remember*
If you do not specify the update_password: on_create option, Ansible re-sets the user password every time the playbook is run: if the user has changed the password since the last time the playbook was run, Ansible re-sets password.